# Installation of pyproj wheel file

Tags: python, pyproj

Installations:
Windows 10, 64 bit.
Python 3.6.5

I am trying to execute pip install -r pyproj-1.9.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl command.
However getting below error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 302, in run
    check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir,
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 341, in get_requirements
    finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 151, in parse_requirements
    for parsed_line in parser.parse(filename, constraint):
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 330, in parse
    for line in self._parse_and_recurse(filename, constraint):
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 335, in _parse_and_recurse
    for line in self._parse_file(filename, constraint):
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 369, in _parse_file
    filename, self._session, comes_from=self._comes_from
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 574, in get_file_content
    content = auto_decode(f.read())
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\encoding.py", line 41, in auto_decode
    locale.getpreferredencoding(False) or sys.getdefaultencoding(),
  File "c:\users\sneka\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 118: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am new to python and not able to solve this error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove -r. It should be  pip install pyproj-1.9.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: I will add that `-r` stands for requirement and its for installing requirement.txt file